# Google extension webstore

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript или другими способами показать кнопку "Установить"?
Мне не смена браузера на хром нужно, а именно эту кнопку показать.Поменяв user agent на хромовский не помогло.
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А смысл, если браузер не поддерживает расширения? А если поддерживает, а кнопки нет, то что это за браузер такой кривой? По вопросу - можно раскопать и что-то придумать, но этого никто просто так делать не будет.

Comment: @Smlnc Мне надо сделать поддержку расширений для своего браузера, в Яндекс.Браузере Альфа на андроиде как-то же работает расширения и есть эта кнопка.

Comment: Для Opera, Yandex https://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/install-chrome-extensions/ и https://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/extension-source-viewer/

Comment: @vering Какого своего? На каком движке?

Comment: @SmInc для платформы Android. Движок который встроенный в Android(Webkit/Blink).

Comment: @vering Во-первых, с 4.4 он Chromium. Во-вторых, ваш браузер все равно не будет поддерживать расширения! Даже с 4.4. Потому что библиотека дает лишь ограниченный доступ, уверен что этого нет. Если только реализовать свой велосипед, но это совершенно неадекватно - правильно взять исходники БРАУЗЕРА хромиума и сделать браузер из них, как и поступил яндекс, но это требует мощное железо (для сборки) и высокую квалификацию (иначе не соберете - в исходниках всегда есть ошибки и недочеты, никто не заботится о вас). А то, что вы делаете, никому и не нужно.